# Getting ERROR with IN_ARRAY when variable is null

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, pdo

I'm developing this calendar that show events inside each date. The events that the user sees is just the events that the user is related. The relationship is made via MySQL many-to-many table. It is working fine. I am having problem only when my user has no events related to him. In that case, the **in_array** php function gives me this error:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: cleanDataArray in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema-navalha\calendario_teste.php on line 51
>
> **Warning**: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema-navalha\calendario_teste.php on line 51

I understand that the problem is that my user gives me no value that later will be calculated by **in_array** function, but I'm not able to figure out a reasonable alternative. The code that matters in this situation is this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE
                      id_events = ( SELECT id_events FROM relationship_events WHERE id_user = ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $idUser);
$stmt->execute();

$rawTimeStamps = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$cleanDateArray = array();

foreach ($rawTimeStamps as $t) {
$rawDate = $t['start'];
$rawDate = getdate($rawDate);
$cleanDate = mktime(0,0,0,$rawDate['mon'],$rawDate['mday'],$rawDate['year']);
$cleanDataArray[] = $cleanDate;
}

for($list_day = 1; $list_day <= $days_in_month; $list_day++):
    
    $calendar.= '<td class="calendar-day">';
        $timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$month,$list_day,$year);
        if (in_array($timestamp, $cleanDataArray)) {

        $date = getdate($timestamp);
        $time_start = mktime(0,0,0,$date['mon'],$date['mday'],$date['year']);
        $time_end = mktime(23,59,59,$date['mon'],$date['mday'],$date['year']);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT title FROM events WHERE start BETWEEN ? AND ?');
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$time_start,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$time_end,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $events = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number day-number-event"><a href="#">'.$list_day.'</a></div><p>'.$events["title"].'</p>';
        } else {
        $calendar.= '<div class="day-number day-number-noevent">'.$list_day.'</div><div id="calendar-events"></div>';
        }

    $calendar.= '</td>';
    if($running_day == 6):
        $calendar.= '</tr>';
        if(($day_counter+1) != $days_in_month):
            $calendar.= '<tr class="calendar-row">';
        endif;
        $running_day = -1;
        $days_in_this_week = 0;
    endif;
    $days_in_this_week++; $running_day++; $day_counter++;
endfor;
```

Hope someone have a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a misspelling, initialized as cleanDateArray and you're passing cleanDataArray...cleanDataArray is not initialized outside of the record retrieval loop. I would just change your initialization and you should be fine.

Comment: MAN, you've just healed my headache!

Comment: Glad to hear it! Just takes another set of eyes sometimes, good luck to you!

Answer (score 2):

Just put an `!empty()` check, prior to the `in_array` check,

```
if (!empty($cleanDataArray) && in_array($timestamp, $cleanDataArray)) {
```